# Received "Welcome back, consider upvoting" message on question that I had already upvoted

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, popups

I googled a question on Vim, followed a link to SuperUser, and got the "Welcome back, consider upvoting" message on a question that *I had already upvoted*.

Is it possible to disable this message for question that the particular user has upvoted?

If not, how about disabling the popup for SO/SE users that have a good voting history? (Maybe having received "Civic Duty" on multiple sites?)

In any case, I'm tagging this 'bug', because I was asked to do something that I could not possibly do, which is never the desired behavior.

[Here is the question.](https://superuser.com/questions/149854/how-can-i-get-gvim-to-display-the-character-count-of-the-current-file)

**Edit:** For the record, I had also upvoted an answer to this question.

Comment: I wonder if this also appears if you come back to your own question, even if it doesn't have any answers or comments?

Comment: That would be tough to test. Ask a question that is ignored for several days, then return to the question directly ...

Comment: upvote it again, man!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will no longer see a message when you've voted on a question or any of its answers.

Comment: I vote on almost everything I see, but the banner still annoys me almost every day.