# Welcome back message suggests to upvote questions and answers even when questions are locked

Tags: bug, up-votes, locked-questions, welcome-back

I just opened a URL to a question on programmers.SE and got the message:

[image: > Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.]<sub>[*image from TheWobbuffet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236881/i-admire-the-popup-but-should-it-be-appearing-on-locked-posts)</sub>

But the question was locked, so I couldn't do what it asked me to do.

I consider this to be a very minor edge case bug and it's likely not worth investing developer time into it. But since this [similar bug got accepted and fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108573) I guess it's worth reporting even if it's just for making you aware of it.

Comment: I upvoted this bug report because a moderator submitted it.

Comment: You're a moderator...unlock and vote!

Comment: @Bart I am not a moderator on programmers ;)

Comment: It is true, if a problem doesnt affect you personally then its not a problem (!)

Comment: Not sure it's a bug, but agree it should be addressed.