# I admire the popup, but should it be appearing on locked posts?

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions, welcome-back

I noticed a wonderful popup reminding the user to upvote answers, but I thought it might confuse some people that it appears on locked posts.

[image: Popup on locked post]